# How to on click get 2 different data sets with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onclick

I basically on click need to insert the data- into a form. The issue is that both forms use the same element classes and when I perform one function it inserts the data but as soon as I click to run the other function it clears the original data. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="inbox-widget nicescroll mx-box">
    <a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#con-close-modal">
        <div class="inbox-item" data-tag="Followers" data-social_type="twitter">
            <p class="inbox-item-date">Click to add</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inbox-item" data-tag="Friends" data-social_type="twitter">
            <p class="inbox-item-date">Click to add</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#con-close-modal">
    <div class="inbox-item2" id="chosen_account" data-social_id="12345">         
    <p class="inbox-item2-date">Click to add social ID</p>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#con-close-modal">
    <div class="inbox-item" id="chosen_account" data-social_id="6789">         
    <p class="inbox-item-date">Click to add social ID</p>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>


<form>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="input" id="social_id" type="text" name="social_id" />
<input type="input" id="social_type" type="text" name="social_type" />
<input type="input" id="chart_type" type="text" name="chart_type" value="line"/>
<input type="input" id="chart_tag" type="text" name="chart_tag"/>
</form>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('.inbox-item').click(function() {
      var social_type_value = $(this).data('social_type');
      var social_type_input = $('#social_type');
      social_type_input.val(social_type_value);

      var chart_tag_value = $(this).data('tag');
      var chart_tag_input = $('#chart_tag');
      chart_tag_input.val(chart_tag_value);

      var social_id_value = $(this).data('social_id');
       var social_id_input = $('#social_id');
       social_id_input.val(social_id_value);
    });
```

I also created a fiddle to show whats happening: https://jsfiddle.net/p18f3dow/1/

Comment: The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp --- first of all, the id 'chosen_account' should be changed, since it is twice inside your markup on the contrary, you can assign the same class to both items, since classes do not have to be unique

Comment: I tried taking out the ID and using the same class but I still have the same problem. I updated the fiddle to reflect: https://jsfiddle.net/p18f3dow/2/

Comment: see my answer - sry for the delay ;)

Answer (score 0):

if i got your problem right, you'd want to use one function - but depending on the clicked element add different data... but don't overwrite the already entered data, when clicked element don't contains relevant data...

why not checking, if the data tag exists, in the first place:

```
$('.inbox-item').click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('social_type')) {
    var social_type_value = $(this).data('social_type');
    var social_type_input = $('#social_type');
    social_type_input.val(social_type_value);
  }

  if ($(this).data('tag')) {
    var chart_tag_value = $(this).data('tag');
    var chart_tag_input = $('#chart_tag');
    chart_tag_input.val(chart_tag_value);
  }
  if ($(this).data('social_id')) {
    var social_id_value = $(this).data('social_id');
    var social_id_input = $('#social_id');
    social_id_input.val(social_id_value);
  }
});
```

this would be the quick and dirty solution, though.

better one would be like storing the complete clicked data objects and iterating through them, filling the correct fields. see https://jsfiddle.net/p18f3dow/4/

therefore you have to ensure that the part behing the data- in your html always matches your id in the form. (had to change it from data-tag to data-chart_tag)

then all you need is a simple function like that:

```
  $('.inbox-item').click(function() {    //when clicked
      var stored_data = $(this).data();  //save everything in an object     
      for (var key in stored_data) {     //iterate through the object
        if (stored_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          $('#' + key).val(stored_data[key]) //create an id with #+key and insert the value
        }
      }
    });
```